# What is a "modern browser"?

Tags: browser

I searched SO before asking this potentially vague question, found many references to 'modern browsers', but no definitions. Since this is a term very widely used and referenced, I was surprised that I couldn't find a definition or even a description on the Internet.

So, what, in June 2018, is considered a modern browser? And what is a modern browser in general, is it only the current major version of each popular browser (i.e. Chrome, Safari, FF, IE, Opera)?

Comment: Pretty much. There is no formal definition, but it is generally understood to refer to browsers that keep up with developments in JavaScript, HTML and CSS, and thus implement the majority of recent specifications (currently, HTML5, ECMAScript 2017, majority of CSS3).

Answer (score 3):

**Modern Browser:** [Reference:](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-a-modern-browser)

A modern browser is any browser that: successfully renders a site that you just built using web standards, without you having written any browser-specific hacks, forks or workarounds; and shows great performance as you navigate it.

**Modern Browser Advantages:** Reference : [Modern Browsers](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tims/2011/02/15/a-modern-browser/)

- Modern browsers are fast. They take full advantage of the underlying platform to render graphics with the GPU, compile and execute JavaScript across multiple CPU cores and ensure that web applications run as close as possible to the same speed as native applications.
- Modern browsers enable rich, immersive experiences that could hitherto only be delivered through a plug-in or native application. They can blend video, vector and raster graphics, audio and text seamlessly without sacrificing performance.
- Modern browsers implement features when they are ready, providing predictable patterns that developers can rely on rather than suddenly breaking or removing specifications. They don’t check off support based on a half-completed implementation written to pass a synthetic test, but validate against a test suite that confirms interoperability.
- Modern browsers do adopt standards at an early stage of readiness so developers can experiment and validate the specification, but clearly delineate unstable prototypes as such.

Comment: So would for example Safari 10 be considered a modern browser under these assumptions?

Comment: Please credit original authors, otherwise its plagiarism. Ref: https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/web-design/why-ie9-is-a-web-designers-nightmare/

Comment: @Ska yes safari 10 comes under modern browsers  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_version_history#Safari_10

Answer (score 1):

> A modern browser is any browser that: successfully renders a site that you just built using web standards,  without you having written any browser-specific hacks, forks or workarounds; and shows great performance as you navigate it.

[Reference.](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/what-is-a-modern-browser)